# EntityManager.merge(obj) delete instead of update or gives null error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have my entities like this:

**Template:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEMPLATE")
public class Template extends BaseEntityIdLong {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3208743090890588897L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "template", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    private Set<TemplateControl> templatesSet;
```

**TemplateControl:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEMPLATE_CONTROLS")
public class TemplateControl extends BaseEntityIdLong implements Comparable<TemplateControl>{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 161243586581385870L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="template_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    private Template template;  

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="template_control_id", nullable=true)
    private TemplateControl parentControl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentControl", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    private Set<TemplateControl> children = new LinkedHashSet<TemplateControl>();


    /** TemplateControl attributes */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "templateControls", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    private Set<ControlAttribute> controlAttributes;

    @Transient
    private int columnIndex;

    @Transient 
    private GuiAttributes attributes;
```

**ControlAttribute:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTROL_ATTRIBUTE")
public class ControlAttribute extends BaseEntityIdLong {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1454089401068519858L;

    @ManyToOne//(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="template_controls_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private TemplateControl templateControls;
```

I have a template which contains some `templateControls`(components like `area`) and in area I have other `templateControl`s(like `buttons`) my problem is when I clone a button and add it in the set of `templateSet`(normally I set his `parentControl` to `null` and template property with the template used) and I remove the original  from children. On `EntityManager.merge(template)` sometimes deletes the `templateControl` and his `ControlAttributes` but it should update it. Sometimes  gives this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "template_controls_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (17226, null).
```

Which comes from controlAttribute cause his templateControl is null but I checked in debug and his templateControl is not null it have a good object. Any suggestion what am I missing?

**UPDATE1:**

**Merge method:**

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName=PersistenceJPAConfig.BEAN_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager entityManager;

public T update(T entity) throws DAOException {
    LOGGER.debug("[DAO] Update entity: " + entity);
    try{
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);

        return (T) entityManager.merge(entity);
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("[DAO] Error while updating entity: " + entity, e);
        throw new DAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

The clone method sure works fine I checked it and coworkers use as well, it`s to long I did not think it will help if I post it.

Comment: can you post the cloning and merging code?

Comment: You have "orphanRemoval=true" specified on your relationships. Orphan Removal is meant only for instances that cannot exist without their parent, so that if they ever get removed, they get deleted automatically.   I assume this is what is happening based on your statement "and I remove the original from children".  If not, provide more details on what exactly you are doing and expect the result to be.

Comment: yeah but I added his clone to the templateSet, like this I think it should update it in database